# describe key for menu-bar items from `menu-bar-open` calls

Tags: help, menu-bar

Preface: I disabled `menu-bar-mode` and bound `<mouse-3>` to `menu-bar-open`, via `(global-set-key [mouse-3] #'menu-bar-open)`

**With this configuration, how can I get help for menu-bar items?**
(My ugly workaround now is to temporary enable `menu-bar-mode` and call help with that enabled)

*Problem is:* pressing `C-h k` and then `mouse-3` brings description for `menu-bar-open`.
What I'd like to get instead, is the same `describe-key` behaviour as on `C-<mouse2>` menus.
This should be done in a way, which does not break on emacs updates (i.e: redefining `describe-key` seems to dangerous).

If there is no way to do above , how could I bind `<mouse-3>` to open the menu-bar *and* get the desired help functionality?

*Edit:* Solution from Tobias is not complete, it does not show `local-menu` and `minor-mode-menus`. Function `mouse-menu-bar-map`, which is called from `menu-bar-open` collects them all.

*Edit2:* `[C-down-mouse-3]` does what I expect, but I can't remap this with:

```
(global-set-key [mouse-3] (lookup-key (current-global-map) [C-down-mouse-3]))
```

Answer (score 1):

The value of the variable `facemenu-menu` is bound to <kbd>C-<mouse2></kbd> and that value is a sparse keymap.

Instead of binding `#'menu-bar-open` to <kbd><mouse-3></kbd> you can also bind the sparse keymap defining the menu bar to <kbd><mouse-3></kbd>:

EDIT: As indicated by [jue](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/15749/jue) t is better to receive the menu bar keymap from `mouse-menu-bar-map` than to use the value of `(lookup-key [menu-bar])` because the menu bar is changed dynamically.
`menu-bar-update-hook` cannot be used for reacting on dynamical changes of the menu bar since that hook is only run when the menu bar is switched on. But an advice for `define-key` does the job as far as I could test it up to now.

```
(defun my-menu-bar-update (&rest _ignore)
  "Update the [mouse-3] menu bar."
  (unless my-menu-bar-update-running
    (let ((my-menu-bar-update-running t))
      (global-set-key [mouse-3] (mouse-menu-bar-map)))))
(my-menu-bar-update)
(add-hook 'menu-bar-update-hook #'my-menu-bar-update)
(advice-add 'define-key :after #'my-menu-bar-update)
```

Comment: too bad, this is not a complete solution, because `local-menu` and `minor-mode-menus` are not displayed. Have a look at function `(mouse-menu-bar-map)` it collects them all.

Comment: @jue I am using `mouse-menu-bar-map` now. Please test again. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry it is not yet fully functional, because the menu-bar-menu needs to be updated on more occasions, ie. switching the mode of a buffer (or to buffers with another mode) is not changing the menu as it should.  Also note, that the `(defvar ...)` is not visible in the above answer.

Comment: Maybe this could be solved by using some more hooks, but seems this is not worth the trouble, since the menu is on `C-<down-mouse-3>` anyway